# How to get fully qualified path of css file?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC how do I get the fully qualified path to my css file
by specifying the relative path.

Eg

Url.Content("~/Content/Print.css")

This returns eg "/Content/Print.css"

Where as I want

http://www.mysite.com/Content/Printcss

Understand the issue?

Malcolm

Comment: You want to get this only in the context of the current request, correct?

Answer (score 6):

Similar to Phil, I would use the Request object.  However, I would look at the Url property.
With the Url, you can call GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) to get the missing part of your address:

```
string address = 
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + 
    Url.Content("~/Content/Print.css");
```

The GetLeftPart should return "http://www.mysite.com" as shown in the doc:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.getleftpart(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably concatenate `Request.UserHostName` and your CSS location:

```
String.Format("{0}/Content/Print.css", Request.UserHostName);
```